# Ubuntu stops booting

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on a clean 80 Gb hard drive **(NO WINDOWS)** from a downloaded and burned copy (from official site) as a boot-able DVD.

**During the boot**, as soon as the USB initialization finishes, I get the following;

**Caldera DR-DOS 7.03** and then **[DA - DOS] A : \ >**
A **flashing block** follows this.

It seems to be waiting on an input response. Maybe not but, that's what it looks like.  I have tried every single letter and number input that I can think of to no avail.

There is NOT an  'A' drive (3½" floppy) installed on my computer and the BIOS is so marked in both the installed devices and in the boot sequence.

The Hard Drive is Empty. This is NOT a dual boot set-up. **The Ubuntu iso IS booting** from the DVD. It reaches a certain point and stops, seemingly waiting on an input

**Is there a way to get past this stop?** I have seen the same problem posted before but the answers are of no help. This is not a dual boot problem. The DOS mentioned is NOT Microsoft DOS.

Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop iso is tailored for the CPU that I use.

I found a post about the same problem from two years ago using Ubuntu 11 point something. This is not a new situation. Obviously not common but not new.

Look see. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110819085436AAi7rwF

Comment: When you boot in a live-session ("Try ubuntu without installing"), the program starts and then stops somewhere before you could do anything? Am I right ?

Comment: Did you run a MD5 check after you burned your DVD ? (to check if your burned ISO was complete)

Comment: As in the link you provided: "If you got [DR-DOS] A:\> You have not made the ISO boot disk right
DR DOS (Didgital Rights Disk Operating System) has nothing to do with Linux"